# How can I set Angular to reload only when I save

Tags: angular, angular-cli

When I run "ng serve". My Angular app re-compile every time I type something in any source file. This bothers me and I want it to re-compile/reload only if I save my changes in VS code. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Just making sure: You got auto-save enabled?

Comment: that's exactly what happened..oh my

Comment: @Loop... could you post an answer? I will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer: Do not enable auto-save ;)